# Bootstrap CDN not applying

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm not sure if it's just because I'm a noob at this or what, but I can't get the bootstrap CDN to work. I copied the CDN from their website and pasted it into the code I was working on, and then a fresh page, as shown below and it's not applying on either. The weird thing is that the CDN from freecodecamp on their bootstrap portion works. What am I doing wrong?

Heres the code

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import jQuery as well (bootstrap uses it) and its best to load it just before your closing  tag so that it doesn't block other loading and is then called with a $(document).ready() wrapper.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
      <p>This is some text.</p> 
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped - if you could mark the soution as accepted then other devs will know the issue has been resolved. Happy coding :)

Comment: My bad thought it fixed it but actually didn't. I copied your code exactly and it's still not working.

Comment: Hey - I loaded that content into notepad++ and ran it - it was erroring out due to something called popper.js - I then grabbed this skeleton from the W# schools site and it works fine. Note that W3 Schools can be very sueful but occasionally is incorrect. This time though they were correct and this skeleton runs fine. Note that the content in the snippet is the NEW working version of the skeleton.